# iOS User Interface Customization Kits?

Tags: ios, user-interface, sdk, look-and-feel

I know that recent versions of iOS have added support for easy customization of the look and feel of its components through its "appearance" functionality.  However, I'm not exactly *artistically inclined*.

Does anyone know of a resource that provides pre-packaged user interface customization kits that are easy to plugin using the iOS appearance APIs?  I'm looking for high-quality look & feel, but also would like to see sample code showing how to integrate it into an application.  I don't really care if its for purchase or free.  I just would like something that looks really slick and high quality.  Thoughts?

**UPDATE:**  Okay, I found a site that does offer what I was looking for.  [AppDesignVault.com](http://www.appdesignvault.com) has pre-packaged app templates (graphics, code, etc.) for iOS applications.  However, I find it hard to believe they're the only ones that offer this.  Has anyone come across similar resources or packages?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not exactly a drop-in replacement, but you might want to take a look at [NUI](https://github.com/tombenner/nui) which is an open-source UI styling library with theme support (themes are written in a CSS styled markup language). Another great resource to look for ready UI components is [cocoa controls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/), again, not exactly drop-in and forgot, but still better than implementing it yourself (although the quality of the stuff there varies a lot).
I'm not aware of any drop-in replacement which offers ready made styles, but I hope these two get you somehow started.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many more, right [here](http://www.queness.com/post/10870/useful-collection-of-ios-tools-and-resources-for-designers).

Once you have those designs, here's a [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21703/user-interface-customization-in-ios-6) to actually implement them in iOS 6.

Answer (score 1):

This is objc custom libs I like and use: http://www.objclibs.com/# . Maybe one of those will strike your fancy?